# CKeditor in Chrome Extension popup issued: "Refused to load frame from 'about:blank' because of Content-Security-Policy."

Tags: google-chrome-extension

CKeditor in Chrome Extension popup issued: "Refused to load frame from 'about:blank' because of Content-Security-Policy."

I am trying to get a chrome extension updated to work with the manifest 2 and new Chrome API's that have currently broken the plugin with the latest version release 18.0.1025.142.

I am using CKEditor in a popup window that is issued by a background page in the extension.

But I get the `Refused to load frame from 'about:blank' because of Content-Security-Policy.2` error -- is there a way to get around this?

#### Update

This could be related: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77947&q=Error%20during%20tabs.executeScript%3A&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome extensions, you cannot access or modify content from protocols other than `file:`, `http:`, `ftp:` and `chrome-extension:` (`data:`, `blob:` and `filesystem:` when the page created the resource themselves).

I considered four approaches to solve the problem:

1. Bind a `beforeload` event to the document, and change the URL when it matches `about:blank`.
   **Does not work**: The CSP is activated before this event is fired.
2. Bind a `DOMNodeInserted` event to the document, and check for `about:blank` iframes.
   **Does not work**: The CSP is activated before this event is fired.
3. Use the [`webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) API to intercept the request.
   **Does not work**: The strict [match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) do not allow the `about:` protocol.
4. Change the `src` property before inserting the IFRAME in the document:

   1. Either manually (best option), or
   2. Modify `document.createElement` for IFrames, or
   3. Modify the `appendChild`, `insertBefore` and `replaceChild` methods for Iframes.

For all methods, you have to create a dummy page, say **`blank.html`** within your extension, and allow access via [`web_accessible_resources`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources).

### Manifest file example (last four lines are important):

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {"scripts": ["aboutblank.js"]},
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["blank.html"]
}
```

### `aboutblank.js`

```
var BLANK_PAGE = chrome.extension.getURL("blank.html");

(function(BLANK_PAGE, createElement, appendChild, insertBefore, replaceChild) {
    HTMLDocument.prototype.createElement = function(str) {
        var elem = createElement.call(this, str);
        if (str.toUpperCase() == 'IFRAME') {
            elem.src = BLANK_PAGE;
        }
        return elem;
    };
    Element.prototype.appendChild = function(newChild) {
        iframe_check(newChild);
        return appendChild.call(this, newChild);
    };
    Element.prototype.insertBefore = function(newChild, refChild) {
        iframe_check(newChild);
        return insertBefore.call(this, newChild, refChild);
    };
    Element.prototype.replaceChild = function(newChild, refChild) {
        iframe_check(newChild);
        return replaceChild.call(this, newChild, refChild);
    };

    function iframe_check(elem) {
        if (elem instanceof HTMLIFrameElement && (elem.src == '' || elem.src.slice(0,11) == 'about:blank')) {
            elem.src = BLANK_PAGE;
        }
    }
})(BLANK_PAGE,
   HTMLDocument.prototype.createElement,
   Element.prototype.appendChild,
   Element.prototype.insertBefore,
   Element.prototype.replaceChild);
```

Note: Option 1 is recommended over modifying these prototype methods. Also, the prototype method does not work for `<iframes>` injected using `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I have solved my particular problem by switching to a simpler editor which allowed for exporting its JS into one js file that I included as a content_script.